# timestamp определенной даты

Tags: timestamp, php

Есть функция time(), она содержит timestamp текущей даты.

А как например узнать timestamp такой даты: 1 января 2013 г. 00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mktime()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mktime.php) - время по фиксированным параметрам
[strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php) - время из произвольной(почти) строки

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите в сторону [mktime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mktime.php)